# How to validate an office color theme XML?

Tags: c#, openxml, .net-5

I want to validate a color theme that I receive from users.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.colorscheme?view=openxml-2.8.1

Example of correct one:

```
<clrScheme name="sample">  
  <dk1>  
    <sysClr val="windowText"/>  
  </dk1>  
  <lt1>  
    <sysClr val="window"/>  
  </lt1>  
  <dk2>  
    <srgbClr val="04617B"/>  
  </dk2>  
  <lt2>  
    <srgbClr val="DBF5F9"/>  
  </lt2>  
  <accent1>  
    <srgbClr val="0F6FC6"/>  
  </accent1>  
  <accent2>  
    <srgbClr val="009DD9"/>  
  </accent2>  
  <accent3>  
    <srgbClr val="0BD0D9"/>  
  </accent3>  
  <accent4>  
    <srgbClr val="10CF9B"/>  
  </accent4>  
  <accent5>  
    <srgbClr val="7CCA62"/>  
  </accent5>  
  <accent6>  
    <srgbClr val="A5C249"/>  
  </accent6>  
  <hlink>  
    <srgbClr val="FF9800"/>  
  </hlink>  
  <folHlink>  
    <srgbClr val="F45511"/>  
  </folHlink>  
</clrScheme>
```

I thought Microsoft would validate the color theme when I make a new object from the class, but it doesn't, even if I try to use it. For example if I use this xml, it would simply take it in, but when I apply it on Power Point, it would say that the file is broken.

```
<clrScheme name="sample">  
  <dk1>  
    <sysClr val="windowText"/>  
  </dk1>  
  <random>  
    <sysClr val="windowText"/>  
  </random>  
</clrScheme>  

 var scheme = new ColorScheme(xmlText);
 var hasChildren = scheme.HasChildren
```

Is there any nice way to validate this?

I have also tried to use a normal XML validation, but I couldn't find anything online. It seems to be a problem that millions of people should have been faced so far so I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Well defined XML will come with an XMLSchema, which can be used to validate the XML.

Comment: @Neil I know their XML schema, but to validate I need an xsd file as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset

Comment: The Open XML documentation includes an XSD (as per the wiki page, and the ISO page), so there is one somewhere.   Your task for the afternoon is to find it :-)

Comment: @Neil, I think if you read my question, I clearly say that I couldn't find anything. If you know where to find it, I would appreciate to share it with me.